# should i draw ER diagram before create database

Tags: java, mysql

I'm going to create a system using java and mysql.
I want to know should i create E-R Diagram before create database.
Help Me.
thanks.

Comment: If you think the process of doing so would be helpful to you in the design stages, yes. If you already know what you're going to do, then no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ER diagrams represent the logical design of the database. It is essential to analyse the data model design before you start creating your entities. Usually it is recommended to draw ER diagrams before you start coding, so that you can ensure good, probably best modelling of your entities.

If you are working on a projects involving Prototypes, POCs, etc.. you can always use reverse engineering tools to draw them for you.

HTH!

Answer (score 0):

The MySQL Workbench provide you with the tools to either reverse engineer your DB into a model, or to create a model which it will then use to create the database for you http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-data-modeling.html. In either case an ER diagram is an essential part of any complete software/database project.